# Using AutoHotKey scripting language is it possible to swap Alt and Ctrl keys and also retain native AltTab key behaviour?

Tags: autohotkey, ctrl

Currently I must <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> & <kbd>Tab</kbd> to perform a traditional `AltTab`.

I've already swapped my <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys. However, I still want to be able to `AltTab` traditionally

This is what I have so far:

```
LCtrl::Alt  
Alt::LCtrl

LCtrl & Tab::AltTab
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LCtrl & Tab::Send {Alt Down}{Tab}{Alt Up}
```

Is the simple answer and will switch between the last 2 open windows.

If you want proper functionality, you'll have to read:
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm
and use it in conjuction with

```
GetKeyState, OutputVar, LCtrl
If OutputVar = "D"
  Send {Tab}
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me

```
LControl & Tab::AltTab
```